# Explicit construction of a representation of Young diagram/tableaux from fundamental representations

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory, lie-groups, lie-algebras, young-tableaux

Given $SU(N)$ fundamental representation say $U^i$ in the fundamental $N$ of $SU(N)$, with indices $i=1,2,3,\dots,N$.

[We can construct a representation whose Young diagram/tableaux look like](http://www.physics.smu.edu/scalise/P4321sp19/solutions/hadron-app-3.pdf)

Given [image]

with a representation of dimensions
$$
\frac{N (N+1) (N-1) (N-2)}{8}.
$$

This seems to have two symmetric tensor indices, and three anti-symmetric tensor indices, totally four tensor indices.

- My question is that how do we write down such a $\frac{N (N+1) (N-1) (N-2)}{8}$-dimensional object based on some tensor construction of
  $$U^iU^jU^kU^l...+...$$
  with some symmetric and/or anti-symmetric tensor indices?

(Thanks!)

Answer (score 1):

This is a rather complicated theory and there are many different variants for how to make this explicit. One of the approaches is to look at tensors with a number of indices equal to the number of boxes, and which are left invariant by the corresponding Young projector. See [this article](http://www.birdtracks.eu/refs/YoungUn.pdf) by Elwang, Cvitanović and Kennedy for a quick introduction.

PS: The tensors should not factorize as products of $U$'s

---

Edit:

Consider the vector space $V$ of tensors $T=(T_{i_1,\ldots,i_n})$ where indices take values from $1$ to $N$ and where the number of indices $n$ is the number of boxes in the Young diagram. For better readability I will write $T(i_1,\ldots,i_n)$ instead of $T_{i_1,\ldots,i_n}$. One has an action of the symmetric group $S_n$ on $V$. For any permutation $\sigma$, it sends the tensor $T$ to $\sigma\cdot T$ whose entries are by definition
$$
(\sigma\cdot T)(i_1,\ldots,i_n):=T(i_{\sigma^{-1}(1)},\ldots,i_{\sigma^{-1}(n)})\ .
$$
Now let $\pi:V\rightarrow V$ be the linear map defined by
$$
\pi(T)=\sum_{\sigma\in R}\sum_{\tau\in C}{\rm sgn}(\tau)\ (\sigma\tau)\cdot T\ .
$$
Here one needs to choose a filling of the boxes by the numbers $1,\ldots,n$ for example $1,2$ in the top row then $3$ then $4$ the bottom rows in the given picture. $C$ is the subgroup of $S_n$ made of permutations which permute these numbers while staying in their assigned columns, and $R$ is the same thing with the rows. It turns out that
$$
\pi\circ\pi=\lambda\pi
$$
for a constant $\lambda$ given by the [product of hook lengths](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hook_length_formula). For the given diagram $\lambda=4\times 1\times 2\times 1=8$.
So $\Pi:=\frac{1}{\lambda}\pi$ is projection onto a subspace ${\rm Im}\ \Pi$ and this is subspace is the wanted irreducible representation (if $N>$ the number of rows for $SU(N)$, $\ge$ for $U(N)$).

Comment: thanks +1 but I want explcit answer if possible. ;./

Comment: Ok did my best, but really one has to read books or at least articles like the one I mentioned, rather than a quick math.stackexchange post, in order to learn this properly.